# calculating the total money up to the mention date using mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, date, min

```
                   membership table
                         membership start date 2011-01-10
                         membership end date 2012-09-08
                         membership monthly amount £120.00
                         member_Id

                    member table
                       member_id
```

the member will pay the money on 10 th of every month...can i get the total amount that the member has paid up to this date  2011-05-15  and is it possible using mysql query.

this is the sql query 
suggested by you guys

```
                    SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, membertomships.memberToMship_StartDate, MIN(membertomships.memberToMship_EndDate,'2011-7-06'))* memberToMship_ChargePerPeriod FROM membertomships WHERE membertomships.member_Id = '1';
```

but it was giving error at memberToMship_EndDate,'2011-7-06' between dates memberToMship_EndDate and this date '2011-7-06'

would you pls explain why it was giving error

Comment: if this question is unclear pls intimate me ..

Comment: Ever heard of a [WHERE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) clause or a [SUM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) function?

Comment: You mean how much they have ever paid to date?

Comment: i want both how much he has to pay upto today and how much he has paid  up to mention date above...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, start_date, MIN(end_date,'2011-05-15')) * amount from membership where membershipId=@memberdshipId
```

for include current date also.......

```
 SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, start_date, MIN(end_date,'2011-05-15')) * amount ,TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, start_date, MIN(end_date,CURDATE())) * amount from membership where membershipId=@memberdshipId
```

this is working fine for me in ms sqlserver please change for mysql syntex

```
select datediff(Month,startdate,enddate)*amount as Enddateamount,
datediff(Month,startdate,'12/6/2010')*amount as amountongivendate,
datediff(Month,startdate,getdate())*amount as amounttoday
 from membership
```

[image: sql server screen shot]

Comment: this will returns the amount that the member has paid up to  this date 2011-05-15 right.. so how we calculate that the amount he has to pay up to today date...

Comment: just change the '2011-05-15' with today date dear.it will give you the amount which he has to pay today date.

Comment: This is exactly the same I've told to in my answer but with parameters not values.

Comment: @Rahul but the sql query is giving error at this place between dates memberToMship_EndDate and this date '2011-7-06'

Comment: this is the error   Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''2011-7-06'))* memberToMship_ChargePerPeriod FROM membertomships WHERE membertom' at line 1

Comment: no its working in ms sql server 2005, for mysql u have to change the datediff with TIMESTAMPDIFF and change the getdate() with curdate().let me know if problem .

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear, I don't think you've explained the schema properly. If you want to get a sum of everything each has paid:

```
select sum(amount) from membership group by member_id
```

Feel free to add a where clause should you wish to restrict it by date or member_id(s):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Comment: he wants to calculate the amount paid between start date of subscription and the date given by him.

Comment: @rahularyansharma well then they need to know how many months between start date and end date of subscription, multiplied by the monthly amount, assuming that hasn't changed since the start date and now.  Your summation of the problem differs from their comment. Do you know them?

Comment: @Raoul i dont know him personally but you see the table structure which is not formatted properly you can also guess whats he wants. now what you answer in last comment is the actually whats he needs. he have only single entry for each user with start_date,end_date,amount,membershipid and he wants to calculate the amount paid by user to any particular date.

Comment: @rahul is it possible to to calculate the amount like this way    (amount today- amount paid up to given date(considering the pay date for every month))* num of months ...

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have only subscription data not all payment table, right?
Then you need such statement

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, '2011-01-10', MIN('2012-09-08', '2011-05-15')) * 120.00
```

Of course you should replace the constants with column names and parameters.

This of course assumes that the payment day 10 is dependent on the subscription start date and the customer has paid on time. :)